# NIntegrate: slow convergence error and speed efficiency

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, numerics

I am trying to produce a plot but `NIntegrate` is very slow and making a number of warnings, I have used `UnitStep[]` to keep the terms real

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Ma = {0.5*10^-3, 105.7*10^-3, 1.777, 2.3*10^-3, 4.8*10^-3, 1.275, 
173.07, 95*10^-3, 4.18};
A1[x_, M1_] := 
p^2/(12 \[Pi])
 M1 (1 + (2 Ma[[x]]^2)/M1^2) ((1 - (4 Ma[[x]]^2)/M1^2)*
 UnitStep[M1 - 2 Ma[[x]]])^(1/2);

A2[x_, M1_] := 
p^2/(12 \[Pi])
M1 (1 + (2 Ma[[x]]^2)/M1^2) ((1 - (4 Ma[[x]]^2)/M1^2)*
 UnitStep[M1 - 2 Ma[[x]]])^(1/2);

At[M1_] := Sum[A1[x, M1], {x, 4, 9}] + Sum[A2[x, M1], {x, 1, 3}];

p = 10^-5;
RR[g_, i_, M1_] := 
p^4/(12 \[Pi]*g)*
Sqrt[(g - 4 Ma[[i]]^2)*UnitStep[M1 - 2 Ma[[i]], g - 4 Ma[[i]]^2]]/
Sqrt[g]*((g) (g + 2 Ma[[i]]^2))/((g - M1^2)^2 + M1^2 At[M1]^2);
ff[g_, i_, M1_] := 
2*p^4/(12 \[Pi]*g)*
Sqrt[(g - 4 Ma[[i]]^2)*UnitStep[M1 - 2 Ma[[i]], g - 4 Ma[[i]]^2]]/
Sqrt[g]*((g) (g + 2 Ma[[i]]^2))/((g - M1^2)^2 + M1^2 At[M1]^2);
sR = 2;
uR[f_] := 6 f^3;

NN1[f_, M1_, i_] := 
sR/(8 \[Pi]^4 uR[f])
NIntegrate[
p^2*k^2*(1 - cs)/((E^(k/f) + 1) (E^(p/f) + 1))*
 RR[2*p*k (1 - cs), i, M1], {p, 0, \[Infinity]}, {k, 
 0, \[Infinity]}, {cs, -1, 1}];
NN2[f_, M1_, i_] := 
sR/(8 \[Pi]^4 uR[f])
NIntegrate[
p^2*k^2*(1 - cs)/((E^(k/f) + 1) (E^(p/f) + 1))*
 ff[2*p*k (1 - cs), i, M1], {p, 0, \[Infinity]}, {k, 
 0, \[Infinity]}, {cs, -1, 1}];

NNt[f_, M1_] := 
Sum[NN1[f, M1, x]*UnitStep[f - Ma[[x]]], {x, 4, 9}] + 
Sum[NN2[f, M1, x]*UnitStep[f - Ma[[x]]], {x, 1, 3}];

  LogLogPlot[{NNt[f, 1]}, {f, 10^-6, 10^6}, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 18, Bold] & /@ {"f", "NNt"}), 
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.005], Red}, {Thickness[0.005], Blue, 
Dashed}, {Thickness[0.005], Green}, {Thickness[0.005], 
Purple}, {Thickness[0.005], Pink}, {Thickness[0.005], Black}}, 
LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 14, GrayLevel[0], 
Bold}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> 500, 
AspectRatio -> 2/3, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Working Code screenshot]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too localized and unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: While @xzczd is correct in making the comment, I want to contribute something small. Before you run a big chunk of code, make sure that the intermediate steps don't cause any issues. Once you break down your code, try to see that this `M1 (1 + (2 Ma[[x]]^2)/M1^2) ((1 - (4 Ma[[x]]^2)/M1^2)*
     UnitStep[M1 - 2 Ma[[x]]])^(1/2);` does not make sense.

Comment: @bmf In the list `Ma`  there are some values for which `M1<2Ma`, so the sq. root term becomes complex. to remove such errors I have used an `UnitStep` inside the square root. I think It is not causing any issues. However, when I kept the `UnitStep` outside it is producing data in form of `0.+0.I`

Comment: @darkknight that's not the issue. Second hint: does `expression[[x]]` make sense? if `x` is not a number?

Comment: @bmf `[[x]]` is just to select respective values from `Ma`

Comment: @darkknight if you focus on the first lines of your code and more specifically up to the point `At[M1_] := Sum[A1[x, M1], {x, 4, 9}] + Sum[A2[x, M1], {x, 1, 3}];` and you run what you have written you will get the following error: `Part::pkspec1: The expression x cannot be used as a part specification.`

Comment: @bmf This is a formatting issue due to copy the code and pasting it here. If you paste it and remove the extra space due to the new line then `x` and `M1` will now be appropriately formatted as variables and you'll not face the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we change the method of integration, we can obtain the `NNt[1,1]` which we see in the screenshot without any errors. The method is `LocalAdaptive`. I provide the full code for convenience

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

then

```
Ma = {0.5*10^-3, 105.7*10^-3, 1.777, 2.3*10^-3, 4.8*10^-3, 1.275, 
   173.07, 95*10^-3, 4.18};
A1[x_, M1_] := 
  p^2/(12 π) M1 (1 + (2 Ma[[x]]^2)/
      M1^2) ((1 - (4 Ma[[x]]^2)/M1^2)*UnitStep[M1 - 2 Ma[[x]]])^(1/
      2);
A2[x_, M1_] := 
  p^2/(12 π) M1 (1 + (2 Ma[[x]]^2)/
      M1^2) ((1 - (4 Ma[[x]]^2)/M1^2)*UnitStep[M1 - 2 Ma[[x]]])^(1/
      2);
At[M1_] := Sum[A1[x, M1], {x, 4, 9}] + Sum[A2[x, M1], {x, 1, 3}];
```

and

```
p = 10^-5;
RR[g_, i_, M1_] := 
  p^4/(12 π*g)*
   Sqrt[(g - 4 Ma[[i]]^2)*UnitStep[M1 - 2 Ma[[i]], g - 4 Ma[[i]]^2]]/
    Sqrt[g]*((g) (g + 2 Ma[[i]]^2))/((g - M1^2)^2 + M1^2 At[M1]^2);
ff[g_, i_, M1_] := 
  2*p^4/(12 π*g)*
   Sqrt[(g - 4 Ma[[i]]^2)*UnitStep[M1 - 2 Ma[[i]], g - 4 Ma[[i]]^2]]/
    Sqrt[g]*((g) (g + 2 Ma[[i]]^2))/((g - M1^2)^2 + M1^2 At[M1]^2);
```

also

```
sR = 2;
uR[f_] := 6 f^3;
```

Now, we set

```
NN1[f_, M1_, i_] := 
  sR/(8 π^4 uR[f]) NIntegrate[
    p^2*k^2*(1 - cs)/((E^(k/f) + 1) (E^(p/f) + 1))*
     RR[2*p*k (1 - cs), i, M1], {p, 0, ∞}, {k, 
     0, ∞}, {cs, -1, 1}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"];
NN2[f_, M1_, i_] := 
  sR/(8 π^4 uR[f]) NIntegrate[
    p^2*k^2*(1 - cs)/((E^(k/f) + 1) (E^(p/f) + 1))*
     ff[2*p*k (1 - cs), i, M1], {p, 0, ∞}, {k, 
     0, ∞}, {cs, -1, 1}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"];
NNt[f_, M1_] := 
  Sum[NN1[f, M1, x]*UnitStep[f - Ma[[x]]], {x, 4, 9}] + 
   Sum[NN2[f, M1, x]*UnitStep[f - Ma[[x]]], {x, 1, 3}];
```

And finally,

```
NNt[1, 1]
```

> `0.00726128`

---

**Edit 1:** this is related to the speed of `NIntegrate`.

We can use [**`"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0`**](https://support.wolfram.com/12485) and also we can modify the [**`PrecisionGoal`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrecisionGoal.html).

The first one is preventing the Wolfram Language Kernel from manipulating the integral symbolically. The second is telling how many digits of precision should be sought after in the final result.

We can do a test for some low-lying values.

The command

```
Table[NNt[xx, 1], {xx, 10^-6, 10}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

for the code as presented in the original answer returns

> `{28.5325, {0., 0.00726131, 0.205248, 1.52811, 6.39666, 19.4617,  48.3472, 104.398, 203.4, 366.375}}`

while the modifications suggested in this edit

> `{0.795043, {0., 0.00726022, 0.20555, 1.52878, 6.39659, 19.4588,  48.2494, 104.423, 202.567, 359.613}}`

One can clearly see the vast improvement in the speed of `NIntegrate` by using these simple steps. Also, the accuracy is not that bad -at least not for my taste.

The code that incorporates the above suggestions is presented below:

```
Ma = {0.5*10^-3, 105.7*10^-3, 1.777, 2.3*10^-3, 4.8*10^-3, 1.275, 
   173.07, 95*10^-3, 4.18};
A1[x_, M1_] := 
  p^2/(12 π) M1 (1 + (2 Ma[[x]]^2)/
      M1^2) ((1 - (4 Ma[[x]]^2)/M1^2)*UnitStep[M1 - 2 Ma[[x]]])^(1/
      2);
A2[x_, M1_] := 
  p^2/(12 π) M1 (1 + (2 Ma[[x]]^2)/
      M1^2) ((1 - (4 Ma[[x]]^2)/M1^2)*UnitStep[M1 - 2 Ma[[x]]])^(1/
      2);
At[M1_] := Sum[A1[x, M1], {x, 4, 9}] + Sum[A2[x, M1], {x, 1, 3}];
p = 10^-5;
RR[g_, i_, M1_] := 
  p^4/(12 π*g)*
   Sqrt[(g - 4 Ma[[i]]^2)*UnitStep[M1 - 2 Ma[[i]], g - 4 Ma[[i]]^2]]/
    Sqrt[g]*((g) (g + 2 Ma[[i]]^2))/((g - M1^2)^2 + M1^2 At[M1]^2);
ff[g_, i_, M1_] := 
  2*p^4/(12 \[Pi]*g)*
   Sqrt[(g - 4 Ma[[i]]^2)*UnitStep[M1 - 2 Ma[[i]], g - 4 Ma[[i]]^2]]/
    Sqrt[g]*((g) (g + 2 Ma[[i]]^2))/((g - M1^2)^2 + M1^2 At[M1]^2);
sR = 2;
uR[f_] := 6 f^3;
NN1[f_, M1_, i_] := 
  sR/(8 π^4 uR[f]) NIntegrate[
    p^2*k^2*(1 - cs)/((E^(k/f) + 1) (E^(p/f) + 1))*
     RR[2*p*k (1 - cs), i, M1], {p, 0, \[Infinity]}, {k, 
     0, ∞}, {cs, -1, 1}, 
    Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 2];
NN2[f_, M1_, i_] := 
  sR/(8 π^4 uR[f]) NIntegrate[
    p^2*k^2*(1 - cs)/((E^(k/f) + 1) (E^(p/f) + 1))*
     ff[2*p*k (1 - cs), i, M1], {p, 0, \[Infinity]}, {k, 
     0, ∞}, {cs, -1, 1}, 
    Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 2];
NNt[f_, M1_] := 
  Sum[NN1[f, M1, x]*UnitStep[f - Ma[[x]]], {x, 4, 9}] + 
   Sum[NN2[f, M1, x]*UnitStep[f - Ma[[x]]], {x, 1, 3}];
```

Having gathered our results in a [**`Table`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) we can [**`ListLogLogPlot`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLogLogPlot.html)

---

**Edit 2:** using the above code

```
ll = Table[NNt[xx, 1], {xx, 10^-6, 75}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

gives

> `{271.461, Null}`

```
ListLogLogPlot[ll, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 18, Bold] & /@ {"f", "NNt"}), 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.005], Red}, {Thickness[0.005], Blue, 
    Dashed}, {Thickness[0.005], Green}, {Thickness[0.005], 
    Purple}, {Thickness[0.005], Pink}, {Thickness[0.005], Black}}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 14, GrayLevel[0], 
   Bold}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> 500, 
 AspectRatio -> 2/3, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: plot]

**Edit 3:** the need for speed.

In addition, to using the steps I described above, you can use [**`ParallelTable`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable.html?v=13.2) to create your list of data.

For instance, see the following

```
ll = ParallelTable[NNt[xx, 1], {xx, 10^-6, 10^2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{313.161, Null}`

```
ListLogLogPlot[ll, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 18, Bold] & /@ {"f", "NNt"}), 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.005], Red}, {Thickness[0.005], Blue, 
    Dashed}, {Thickness[0.005], Green}, {Thickness[0.005], 
    Purple}, {Thickness[0.005], Pink}, {Thickness[0.005], Black}}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 14, GrayLevel[0], 
   Bold}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> 500, 
 AspectRatio -> 2/3, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: pplot]

**Edit 4:** another idea that comes to mind is use a particular `Method` in `ParallelTable`

```
ll = ParallelTable[NNt[xx, 1], {xx, 10^-6, 10^2}, 
    Method -> "FinestGrained"]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{260.542, Null}`

which is faster compared to the version without a specified method but unfortunately not by a lot.

Comment: Surprisingly, even with a list of errors the result is the same as above with `LocalAdaptive`, and taking too much time for plotting

Comment: @darkknight well for one you are plotting over a large region `{f, 10^-6, 10^6}` a complicated and not an elementary expression. You can break up the computation. Secondly, `Mathematica` many times provides a result even with errors. Sometimes this is correct and sometimes is not. I tend to trust results for which `Mathematica` does not complain. Finally, fixing a chunk of code is one thing. Optimizing the code is another thing :)

Comment: If possible can you please also reproduce a smooth plot from this code what is my ultimate goal? Then I should mark this as a right solution

Comment: @darkknight whether you mark it as a right solution or not, my humble opinion is that since I solved the error that was generated and showed you already one trick to reduce the computation time, this is the right solution. I will show you another one that reduces the computation time even more, , but don't expect me to do your homework for you. And as a matter of fact, I find it quite crass that you would write something like that, without having even upvoted-not accepted- an answer that solves the two central issues you had

Comment: Well, one needs at least 15 reputation for upvoting…

Comment: @xzczd ok fair point. I did not remember that. but I still think that it's not polite what was written previously. I tried to update the title to make it more relevant for the site, and presented some thoughts. I don't think that my suggestions were that bad. anyway, it seems that you can keep some of the people happy some of the times, but not everyone happy all the times :-)

Comment: @bmf I am extremely sorry, I was about to accept it as the right solution just giving it 2-3 day time

Comment: @bmf also I should appreciate that you have presented a good well written and helpful solution

Comment: @darkknight don't sweat it. it was just a misunderstanding :-). I am mellowing with age. For the record, you **should** wait a couple of days before accepting an answer, and you **should** provide some feedback for the suggested solutions. So, all is well. Good luck with your computations and see you around!